# access to Application's certificates in K8S:

Tags: kubernetes, certificate

Application's certificates in K8S:

im working on a project which i need to get the certificates of the installed applications in the node.
how K8S handle the applications certificates?
how can i get those certificates?
Currently i have simple configuration in Azure with ingress as ssl terminator and application

Comment: wdym by application certs? tls certs?

Comment: yes - i mean to tls cert